# My nginx setup is giving a redirect loop

Tags: nginx

Below is my Nginx.conf -

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
   worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
 include       mime.types;
 default_type  application/octet-stream;

 #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
 #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
 #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

 #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

 sendfile        on;
 #tcp_nopush     on;

 #keepalive_timeout  0;
 keepalive_timeout  65;

 gzip  on;
 gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
 include /usr/local/nginx/conf/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

my sites-available conf -

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name 1.2.3.4;
    #server_name abc.in;

    access_log  /usr/local/nginx/logs/abc.access.log;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/abc;
    }
 }
```

On the browser I am getting two slashes "//" after I type in the IP address and the message "This web page has a redirect loop". Can anyone please help me identify the problem please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reading documentation: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule

> While passing request nginx replaces URI part which corresponds to
>   location with one indicated in proxy_pass directive.

You should add trailing slash '/' after abc to not loose it after transformation or you will get /abcindex.html, not /abc/index.html.